# React Native - Save image with overlay sticker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, react-native, expo

I have a use case where I'd like to place a sticker on top of an image the user has chosen from his/her storage (or shot with camera), and upload the result to a webservice.

Ideally, the user can drag the sticker to place it on the image as needed, maybe even pinch-to-zoom and rotate, but the bare minimum would just be to overlay the sticker in a fixed position in the Image component and save the result to a file to be uploaded.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I've searched quite a bit, and haven't been able to figure it out yet. My best bet so far is to show the result to the user with nested images

```
<Image source={[USER_IMAGE]} style...>
  <Image source={[STICKER]} />
</Image>
```

and then draw and save the result on a canvas on the backend.

Comment: I too would like to know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using `react-native-gesture-handler` for this, an example can [be found here](https://snack.expo.io/@jhalborg/sticker-example). I've updated it since then, but that snack should be enough to get anyone else going :-)

Comment: This is the part where I can drag and place sticker but what about saving how to save that image with an overlay on it?

Comment: @DarshanJain Use `https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/take-snapshot-async/` for Expo or `https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot`

Comment: But I do not want to use Expo modules in my project

Comment: Then use the other one? :)